# Volley doesnt pass post parameters

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I´m using Volley in my Android project to connect it to a server.

I need to send data with `post` method to url and get response but volley don´t pass my data.

here is my code:

```
StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jres=new JSONObject();
                        jres.opt(response);
                        if(jres.getString("value").toLowerCase()=="true"){
                            ConfirmMob=txtMob.getText().toString();
                            SubmitMob();
                        }
                        else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(App.getContext());
                            dialog.setMessage(R.string.IncorrectMob);
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    loading.hide();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("IsMobValid - " + error.networkResponse, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            error.printStackTrace();
            error.networkResponse
            loading.hide();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("x", "IsMobValid");
            params.put("Mob", txtMob.getText().toString());
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }

    };

    App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

how can i fix it to work?
is there any wrong?

Comment: did you got any error message `onErrorResponse`?

Comment: No @yaa110.  in server side error occured because request need some parameters but in my request volley dont send them to server

Comment: Did you start the requestqueue?

Comment: in last line of above code, when request adds in requestQueue , request starts @ElDuderino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think volley is Defective!

In requesting by `JsonObjectRequest` never passed parameters at all.
In requesting by `StringRequest` if sending custom headaer , that sounds HTTPRequest is not Normal. Because my server causes `500 Error`!

by Removing below code, My problem is Solved.

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON requests were all failing, because on the serverside, all POST parameters were empty!  My node.js server with Express, was using the express.bodyparser(), which previously had worked just fine locally. 
What was also weird, was that the headers were working just fine.

After lots of searching, and asking for help in the Volley users group, I came across a tip, to set the charset on the content type header. Because without it, the bodyparser fails to parse that parameters correctly.
So, the correct content-type headers should be:

> application/json; charset=utf-8

and The correct content-type header is set at line 25:

```
Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();  
jsonParams.put("param1", youParameter);

JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(  
    Request.Method.POST,
    "https://your.url/here",
    new JSONObject(jsonParams),

    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            verificationSuccess(response);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            verificationFailed(error);
        }
    }) {

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");
    return headers;
}
};
MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(myRequest, "tag");
```